# how to customise UISegmentedControl items

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

how to customise UISegmentedControl items with different type of orders instead of rectangular images and changing the image for selected state.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background image using an UIImage.

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

There's a great tutorial available here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6

Answer (score 0):

Refer Apple Documentation: [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2). Apple has already given documentation for customizing this control.

Apart from this, here are few other tutorial links:

http://techblog.chegg.com/2013/01/11/customizing-appearance-of-uisegmentedcontrol/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i use PLSegmentView available from [here](https://github.com/xhan/PlutoLand/tree/master/PlutoLand/UI). It allows you to simply swap out the regular UISegmentedControl and supply an image for each of the two states for each segment. works well.